# Replacing data in JSON using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, oracle, replace

The below JSON data is one of the field in the table. In the below JSON data,  I need to replace the value which have "Not available" in the `expLevel` into "Not listed" using SQL query.

```
"Information": {
        "Name": [],
        "Class": [],
        "Degree": ["Graduate or professional degree"],
        "major": [],
        "skill": [],
        "expLevel": ["0 to 2 years",
                     "Not available",
                     "3 to 5 years"],
        "certificationtype": ""
    }
```

I have tried this:

```
update sr set filter = replace(filter, '"Not available"', '"available" , "listed"')
from sharedreports_check sr 
where filter like '%"expLevel":[[]"%Not available%"%'
```

But it is not worked.

Please let me know what will be the SQL query to replace it.

Comment: FYI , Now Json is supported in sql server 2016.Now we can query on json type just as we query in xml type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
update sr set filter = replace(filter, 'Not available', 'Not listed')
from sharedreports_check sr 
where filter like '%expLevel%Not available%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can manipulate this json in front end then it is better.

Another option is to create CLR,if it is very frequent work and data get populated from other source .

Try this script,i think it will work.(for test test try few more example).
Also there is no need of where clause.

```
declare @i nvarchar(max)='"Information": {
        "Name": [],
        "Class": [],
        "Degree": ["Graduate or professional degree"],
        "major": [],
        "skill": [],
        "expLevel": ["0 to 2 years",
                     "Not available",
                     "3 to 5 years"],
        "certificationtype": ""
    }'

-- 1st method
select replace(@i, 'Not available', 'Not listed')

-- 2nd method which is more accurate
select replace(substring(col1,0,charindex(']',col1)),'Not available', 'Not listed') from
(select substring (@i,charindex('expLevel"',@i)+len('expLevel"')+1,len(@i)) Col1)t4
```